# API for posting reviews on Google plus account from website

Tags: google-plus

Does the Google plus api allow to post review data to a specific Google plus page, given the user is signed in to their own Google plus account?

I know previously Google plus api was a *read only* api. Is this still the case?

I can see that there is a [review action](https://developers.google.com/+/api/moment-types/review-activity)  in the api, but i'm not too sure if it applies to what i need it for as there are no examples.

Any suggestions or answers will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?